# Foreign KEY constraint failed on django model instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I try to create a model instance upon an action. I can't get the process to a success. I receive an error message on FOREIGN KEY CONSTRTRAINT FAILED, and I'm stuck.
Here is the view where I try to create the model instance for the model Return.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def return_book(request,pk):
    books = Books.objects.filter(school = request.user.school).get(id = pk)
    if books:
        Return.objects.create(borrowed_item_id=books.id,returner_id=request.user.school.id)
    return redirect("view_books")
```

The models

```
class Books(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Issue(models.Model):
    borrower_id = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Books,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Return(models.Model):
    return_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    borrowed_item = models.ForeignKey(Issue,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    returner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

And the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Django\test projects\library manage\lib_system\Library-System\libman\views.py", line 216, in return_book
    Return.objects.create(borrowed_item_id=books.id,returner_id=request.user.id)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

This is the error posted by postgresql

```
insert or update on table "libman_return" violates foreign key constraint "libman_return_borrowed_item_id_b84dde78_fk_libman_issue_id"
DETAIL:  Key (borrowed_item_id)=(9) is not present in table "libman_issue".
```

Comment: Is that the complete traceback? There should atleast be some line pointing to your code in the traceback (none in what you show). Please show the _full_ traceback.

Comment: The full traceback has been updated...

Comment: `returner_id=request.user.school.id`, here I see `returner` is a foreign key to `CustomUser`, but `request.user.school.id` implies it is an id of some model instance like `School` (guessing the name here)? Perhaps you need to write `returner_id=request.user.id`?

Comment: It hasn't shown any difference. The response is the same.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat. I added another component that can help you help me debug this error.

Comment: Ah, `borrowed_item` is a foreign key to `Issue` yet you pass it the id of a `Books` (Note: model names should ideally be **singular** hence `Book` would have been a better name) instance, see the issue?

Comment: Create an answer so I can understand better...Thanking for this help.